# Does IFrames keep objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im doing a small program using html and javascript. I am using the following code to swap a div from my main page with the body of another page :

```
function apresentarPaginaEmDiv(div, url) {
            var iframe;
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
            iframe.src = url;
            iframe.onload = function () {
                var iFrameBody;
                if (this.contentDocument) { // FF, Safari, Chrome
                    iFrameBody = this.contentDocument.body;
                }
                else if (this.contentWindow) { // IE
                    iFrameBody = this.contentWindow.document.body;
                }
                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = iFrameBody.innerHTML;
                document.body.removeChild(this);
            }; ;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
```

so it only appends the Body, therefor, the Head is always the same and so is the JavaScript file and its associated objects right ???

So say i have a Var example = "Hello";
if i swap from Page 1 to Page 2, i will keep that var ???

Im asking because its working with some functions and not with others. I wanted to know if it is correct to do this and if it really keeps my variables.

EDIT :

```
function Clinica ()
{
 this.id = 0;
 this.doentes = new Array();


}

Clinica.prototype.criarDoente = function ()
{
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var sexoM = document.getElementById("masculino");
    var sexoF = document.getElementById("feminino");
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    var sexo;
    alert("ID ATUAL " + this.id);

    if (Clinica.verificarCriacaoDoente(nome,sexoM,sexoF,data))
    {
        if (sexoM.checked)
        sexo = "Masculino";
        else
        sexo ="Feminino";

        var d = new Doente(nome, sexo, this.id, data);
        this.id++;
        this.doentes.push(d);

        alert(d.nome);
        alert(this.id);
        alert(d.dataNascimento);
        alert(cl.doentes.length);
        apresentarPaginaEmDiv("conteudo","Doentes.html");

    }




}
```

So i have this class Clinica witch contains an array of Doentes and an ID. Doente is a class too.
So in one iFrame i insert a bunch of data in the array. then i do those Alerts u see in CriarDoente, just for test purposes. Then i go to another page (via iFrame so i dont reload) and when i check the array lenght it says its undefined. Thats why i think it doesnt keep the data.
Note: cl is an object of class clinica i initialized on this very file.

Comment: You should not lose anything from the page. I did not previously understand what you are doing with that code. Replacing the whole body of the function with `document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = 'foo';` has the same destructive effect on the parent as the original: _none whatsoever_.

Comment: so i can do this instead of the whole DOM code ?

Comment: No. You should keep doing what you are doing now. Add an example of something that's being "lost" so we can find out _why_. It's not because of the iFrames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variable 'example' were declared in the parent document it would still be available when the src of the iframe changes. If it is declared within the iframe it wouldn't be. I think the solution would be to declare it in the parent document if it needs to persist between pages. BTW are you using iframes for any particular reason? Only ask as they generally aren't used these days.

Comment: well i only load the javascript file on the parent document so i guess thats it. Im only using iframes because i dont know ajax and i found it simpler than changing the page using pure DOM.

Comment: That's fine then it should still be there when the content of the iframe changes. For what you're doing it does sound like you would be better off using jQuery and AJAX to load your content though. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted ;-)

Comment: its done mate :D Now i can't understand why the properties of the object all go undefined when i change page :O

Comment: Providing the javascript is in the parent it shouldn't be wiped out by changing pages unless there is some code somewhere doing that. I've set up a quick jsfiddle to show how you can change pages and your values won't be lost. http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/zmhbom54/1/